# Catch clause not working with hive_context.read.json function

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, pyspark, cloudera

I have this PySpark script:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)

sc.addFile("hdfs:///user/cloudera/2904/src/LogFunction.py")
import LogFunction

try:
    df = hive_context.read.json("/user/cloudera/Projet/pareeam.json")
except IOError:
    LogFunction.WarnLog("Nope")
....
....
```

This is my LogFunction.py:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)

df = hive_context.read.json("/user/cloudera/2904/param.json")
Path = df[df.column.isin("LogRep")].collect()[0][1]
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s')

debug_handler = RotatingFileHandler(Path+ '/LogDebug.log', 'a', 1000000, 1)
debug_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
debug_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(debug_handler)
info_handler = RotatingFileHandler(Path+ '/LogInfo.log', 'a', 1000000, 1)
info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
info_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(info_handler)
warning_handler = RotatingFileHandler(Path+ '/LogWarning.log', 'a', 1000000, 1)
warning_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
warning_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(warning_handler)

error_handler = RotatingFileHandler(Path+ '/LogError.log', 'a', 1000000, 1)
error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
error_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(error_handler)

def WarnLog(a):
    logger.warning(a)
```

Anyway, I am sure that My logging is functioning because I already tried it with other errors (// Divide by zero exception).

But it seems like it is not with this example. While executing the script I get a

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.json.
: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/Projet/pareeam.json does not exist.
```

on the terminal but nothing in my Warning file. Any help why isn't it catching the error? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are catching a wrong exception. Your code captures `IOError` while `DataFrameReader.json` throws `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError` (internally) and `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException`

Change your code to

```
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException

try:
    df = hive_context.read.json("/does/not/exist")
except AnalysisException:
    LogFunction.WarnLog("Nope")
```

Comment: I tried that. I'm getting : except AnalysisException:
NameError: name 'AnalysisException' is not defined

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to import it. But i did it now and i am now having another problem: It doesn't catch the exception. the script crushes on the console with a java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/Projet/parDam.json does not exist.

Comment: I have a similar issue here... Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

After you import AnalysisException, you should catch the IOError

```
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException


try:
    df = hive_context.read.json("/does/not/exist")
except IOError:
    LogFunction.WarnLog("Nope")
```